# Creating sections for years from array of dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array that I need to display in a `UITableView` in sections.

I am currently displaying the objects in date order all under one section but I need to section them by year and I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

My object is something like...

```
@interface MyEvent : NSObject

@property NSDate *date;
@property NSString *title;
@property NSString *detail;

@end
```

My array is an array of these objects in date order.

Can I do this straight from this array or do I need to separate the array into a 2D array.

i.e. An NSArray of NSArrays where each object in the second NSArray is in the same year.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do using [`TLIndexPathDataModel`](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html) from [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) as your data structure. The block-based initializer provides one of a few ways to organize the data into sections:

```
NSArray *sortedEvents = ...; // events sorted by date
TLIndexPathDataModel *dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:sortedEvents sectionNameBlock:^NSString *(id item) {
    MyEvent *event = (MyEvent *)item;
    NSString *year = ...; // calculate section name for the given item from date
    return year;
} identifierBlock:nil];
```

And then the data source methods become very straightforward using the data model APIs:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.dataModel.numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId = ...;
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...; // dequeue cell
    MyEvent *event = [self.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ... // configure cell
    return cell;
}
```